# get value for a resource from another resource in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, staticresource

I want SystemColors.ControlBrushKey to have same color as SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey. How do I specify it in XAML? I've tried:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
```

But it throws an exception: *"Cannot find resource named 'SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey'. Resource names are case sensitive.".*
Then I've tried:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static Member=SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
```

And the exception is:
*'#FF3399FF' is not a valid value for property 'Color'.*
After that I've tried:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{x:Static Member=SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
```

And I've also got an error: *"'HighlightBrush' is not a valid value for property 'Color'."*

So how do I specify it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                 Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}"/>
```

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 I'll fill in the blanks since he didn't explain this. You're trying to assign a *brush* to a *color* which is not the same thing. Instead, using `HighlightColorKey` will work.  You can use Expression Blend to do this very easily with a GUI.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work because HighlightColorKey and HighlightBrushKey have different colors.

Comment: @Erode how do I get a color from a brush in a binding?

Comment: @Bogdan0x400 Well, it's *pure theory*, I haven't checked any references but you might try something like this:     `Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}, Path=Color}"`

Comment: I'm quite sure they have **not** different colors by default. Probably you have changed the color or brush somewhere. There you could set the Brush before you make other changes.